# Docker container's image name issue

Tags: docker

I am running Docker version 17.12.1-ce.

I have a confusion with naming and setting names of containers and/or images.

I do not know how to set the IMAGE name to be displayed as wanted.

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                    NAMES
a940a1fc8cd6        eaa0022f09d0         "/bin/sh -c 'set -ex…"   15 hours ago        Exited (4) 15 hours ago                            psql-Base-test-1
78f14cde1e83        mycomp/postgres:10   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 weeks ago         Up 6 weeks                0.0.0.0:5402->5432/tcp   psql-Base-test-2
```

I want the image **eaa0022f09d0** also give a speakable/readable name like **mycomp/postgres:9.6**.

When I take a look at the images it looks properly set up:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
mycomp/postgres     9.6                 eaa0022f09d0        15 hours ago        37.8MB
mycomp/postgres     10                  46f8aa84d854        8 weeks ago         666MB
```

Do I need to start a container from an image before the naming takes place properly?

One confusion issue for me is how the **IMAGE** column on *docker ps* command is connected to an image listed by *docker images*. It seems not to be necessarily the **IMAGE ID** but rather sometimes a mix from **REPOSITORY** and **TAG** and **IMAGE ID**.

Can someone share my confusion or enlighten me?
As I see I successfully managed it like half a year ago but now consuion grew...

Comment: The container id is the actual id of the container which is generated when the container is added. You can name the containers with the `--name` flag and use this name when you running commands against that container. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#container-identification

Answer (score 1):

When you do a `docker ps -a`, it displays all your containers. In this, it shows you the `containerID` the hash of the container, `IMAGE` which is your image name with the tag, the `command` the container started with, the `created` and `status` of the container, any mapped `ports` and lastly the `name` of the container given when creating the container

The `docker images` command shows you all the images present on your system

You can use

`docker build --tag yourImageName:yourTag .`

then you can run the image using

`docker run -d --name YourDesiredName yourImageName:yourTag`